# Problema al traer datos con Ajax a dos bases de datos

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

Tengo un problema al traer datos con Ajax, estoy trayendo los datos de dos bases de datos diferentes con una columna similar que se llama **"codcli"**

Mi estructura es la siguiente **"climae"** en base de datos **"comsysn"** y tengo una tabla de **"ordint"** en base de datos **"traficon"**;

En la tabla de **"climae"."comsysn"** tengo nombres de clientes **"nomcli"."climae"** y código de clientes **"codcli"."climae"**;

En la tabla de **"ordint"."traficon"** tengo código de clientes al que pertenecen esos trabajos **"codcli"."ordint"** y tengo los trabajos **"trabajos"."ordint"**.

Tengo un campo select en html donde tengo un listado de clientes con el **value** del código de cliente, y abajo de el select tengo los datos de mi otra base de datos que son trabajos que también trae el campo código de cliente pero al seleccionar una opción me limpia los datos y lo que quiero hacer es que solo me muestre los datos del cliente selecionado.
Mi problema es que no se como pasar el código de cliente para que lo valide y me muestre los datos del cliente selecionado

Mi código es el siguiente

```html
<?php   
 //load_data_select.php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "comsysn");
 $connecttwo = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "traficon");
 $connect->set_charset("utf8");
 $connecttwo->set_charset("utf8");
 function fill_brand($connect)  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM climae";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '<option value="'.$row["codcli"].'">'.$row["nomcli"].'</option>';  
      }  
      return $output;  
 }  
 function fill_product($connecttwo)  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM ordint";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connecttwo, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '<div class="col-md-3">';  
           $output .= '<div style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">'.$row["trabajo"].'';  
           $output .=     '</div>';  
           $output .=     '</div>';  
      }  
      return $output;  
 }  
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Merge Data of Customers with Ordint</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container">  
                <h3>  
                     <select name="Customers" id="Customers">  
                          <option value="">Seleccione cliente</option>  
                          <?php echo fill_brand($connect); ?>  
                     </select>  
                     <br /><br />  
                     <div class="row" id="show_ordint">  
                          <?php echo fill_product($connecttwo);?>  
                     </div>  
                </h3>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#Customers').change(function(){  
           var codcli = $(this).val();  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"load_data.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{codcli:codcli},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#show_ordint').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

load_data.php

```html
<?php
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "traficon");
 $connect->set_charset("utf8");
$output = '';  
if(isset($_POST["Customers"]))  
{  
if($_POST["Customers"] != '')  
{  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ordint WHERE codcli = '".$_POST["Customers"]."'";  
}  
else  
{  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ordint";  
}  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{  
$output .= '<div class="col-md-3"><div style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">'.$row["trabajo"].'</div></div>';  
}  
echo $output;  
} 
 ?>
```

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por responder,  en este script tengo el problema `<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#Customers').change(function(){  
           var codcli = $(this).val();  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"load_data.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{codcli:codcli},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#show_ordint').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>`

Comment: Tengo tablaA en base de datosA y tablaB en base de datosB lo que quiero hacer es que una columna que tengo en tabla A se valide con TablaB es decir que si seleciono en el html una opccion supongamos Cliente1 que vaya a buscar en las tablaB cuales son registros que tienen en esa base de datos y me muestre solo los datos de Cliente1

Comment: `<?php
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "traficon");
 $connect->set_charset("utf8");
$output = '';  
if(isset($_POST["Customers"]))  
{  
if($_POST["Customers"] != '')  
{  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ordint WHERE codcli = '".$_POST["Customers"]."'";  
}  
else  
{  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ordint";  
}  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{  
$output .= '<div class="col-md-3"><div style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">'.$row["trabajo"].'</div></div>';  
}  echo $output;  
} 
 ?>  `

Comment: @gbianchi Mira el resto

Comment: Igual sigo sin enteder tu problema. Si esta en una u otra base que importa, solo haces el query a la base que queres.

Comment: El problema es que al seleccionar una opción no me trae nada de datos y me quita el resto de datos que traigo cuando cargo la página, LO QUE NECESITO HACER ES VALIDAR QUE AL SELECIONAR ALGO ME TRAIGA SOLO ESOS DATOS PERO NO SE COMO HACER EXACTAMENTE

Comment: Exacto mi problema es el ajax, no se como pasarle el código de cliente para que busque en mi otra base de datos los trabajos que pertenecen a ese cliente y me los traiga, Gracias ese fue mi problema no especificar eso

Comment: Usa el boton [edit]. Arregla tu pregunta en base a lo que hablamos, y especifica claramente tu pregunta. Fijate que aca no importa de que base vienen los datos ni nada de eso, lo que esta pasando es que ajax te limpia la pantalla y no deberia.

Comment: Gracias lo haré, pensé que tenía que trabajar algo sobre las bases de datos para que me dectara los campos de código de cliente

Comment: Por lo menos, por lo que me contas, tu problema no parece tener nada que ver con la base de datos. Vos mismo estas diciendo que te quita los datos que tenias antes, asi que pareceria ser un problema de vista.

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por la ayuda! Hablar contigo me ayudo a ver mi problema en el ajax